# Cron jobs in websphere

Tags: java, spring, websphere

I am using IBM websphere v 7.0. I want to use cron jobs for logging purposes. Is there any way to use cron jobs in Websphere?

Comment: You can try with Quartz framework for scheduling jobs.  Even it supports cron expressions for defining schedules.

Answer (score 4):

WebSphere Application Server (WAS) v7.0 includes a scheduler (WAS Console > Resources > Schedulers). To implement a CRON like calendar set the UserCalendar on the TaskInfo object, for example:

```
taskInfo.setUserCalendar(null, "CRON");
taskInfo.setStartTimeInterval("5 * * * ?");
```

Comment: InfoCenter link might be useful: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/welc6tech_sch_adm.html